# Downloading Blob from Firebase Storage return 403

Tags: python-3.x, firebase-storage

I am trying to download a file from Firebase Storage, but when I use the function donwload_to_filename or download_as_string I get an error. My code is as follows:

With function download_to_filename

```
client = storage2.Client()
buckets = client.list_buckets()
for bucket in buckets:
     print(bucket.name)
bucket = client.get_bucket('tmjback.appspot.com')
#blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs())
list_of_blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix="informe/ordenes/14731d14000000/124b399e000000"))
print(len(list_of_blobs))

path_to_file = str(BASE_DIR) + "test" + ".txt"
file = open(path_to_file, 'w+')
file.write("")
file.close()

Blob.download_to_filename(path_to_file)
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: download_to_filename() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
```

So I try like this:

```
Blob.download_to_filename(filename=path_to_file)
```

But I get this error

```
TypeError: download_to_filename() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

With function download_as_string

```
client = storage2.Client()
buckets = client.list_buckets()
for bucket in buckets:
     print(bucket.name)
bucket = client.get_bucket('tmjback.appspot.com')
#blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs())
list_of_blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix="path/to/folder"))
print(len(list_of_blobs))

blob = Blob.from_string("gs://path/to/folder")
file = blob.download_as_string(client=client)
file = file.loads(file)
```

Error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/informe/o/ordenes%2F14731d14000000%2F124b399e000000%2F201908.json?alt=media: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)
```

I am using the credentials from a user with owner priviliges
What am I doing wrong?